# JQuery selector problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery selector that looks like:

```
var val = "John's cars";
$('#subject input[value="'+val+'"]')
```

This works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer 8, but not in IE 6 or IE7.
The problem is the ' in the text search for. 
Someone has any idea how to work around this problem except to loop through all inputs in question and do a string compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var val = "John's cars";
$('#subject input').filter(function() {
    return this.value == val;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the `'` with a backslash

```
var val = "John\'s cars";
$('#subject input[value="'+val+'"]')
```

from [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

> Special characters in selectors
>
> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters described above as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with a backslash
>   (). Since Javascript uses the
>   backslash for escape sequences in
>   string literals, you must use two
>   backslashes (\) in string literals so
>   that a single backslash will be put
>   into the string.
>
> Example:

```
"#foo\\:bar"
"#foo\\[bar\\]"
"#foo\\.bar"
```

> The full list of characters that need
>   to be escaped: `#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/`

**EDIT:**

since the value is in a string literal, it needs to be double-escaped. So this works

```
var val = "John\\'s cars";
$('#subject input[value="'+val+'"]')
```

Thanks to [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ulf - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hmmm... strange. It doesn't seem to work in Firefox 3.5 either. Looks like using `filter` is the best way

Comment: Your `\'` is in a JavaScript string literal, where it means `'`. You need another level of escaping: `"John\\'s cars"` to get the real backslash character into the selector string. [dear lord, StackOverflow's own handling of backslashes is broken...]

Comment: @bobince - thanks! I thought it may be something small that I was missing :)

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's the apostrophe in the search value - try escaping it using

```
"John\'s cars"
```